# angular js routing trouble

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I am unable to get my code working. I am a newbiew on JS and trying to implement some example I found online on routing on angularJs. I have spent many hours trying to fix it, but could not.

Issue : Default View(View2) is opened by $routeProvider configuration. However, when I redirect this to view2.htm to view1.htm but blank page opens up.
Please help !

HTML CODE

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href="JS/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <link href="/JS/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <link href="JS/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <link href="JS/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="JS/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.map" />
    <link href="JS/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="JS/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot" />
    <link href="JS/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg" />
    <link href="JS/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf" />
    <link href="JS/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" />
</head>
<script src="JS/jquery-2.1.1.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="JS/angular.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/JS/angular-route.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/JS/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    
</script>
<script src="/JS/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">     
</script>
<body>
    <title>::DEMO APP:: </title>
    <div data-ng-app="demoApp1">
        <script src="DemoJS.js" language="text/javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <div class="container">
            <h3>
                All the examples AngularJS Here:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid" data-ng-view="">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

View1.htm Markup

```
<div  id="View1" >
 <h2>
    Example 4 & 5
 </h2>
 <div class="container">
    Name &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" data-ng-model="inputData.name" placeholder="Name" />
    <br />
    City&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" data-ng-model="inputData.city" placeholder="City" />
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="addCustomer()">
        Add Customer</button>
    <br />
    Filter&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" data-ng-model="nameText" placeholder="Filters" />
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="customer in customers |filter:nameText">{{customer.name|uppercase}}
            - {{customer.city}} </li>
    </ul>
  <a ng-href="#/View2.htm">View2</a>
</div>
</div>
```

View2.htm Markup

```
<div id="View2">
<h2>
    Example 1,2 and 3</h2>
<div class="container">
    <h3>
        Data Binding Fundamentals</h3>
    <h4>
        Using a Data Binding Template</h4>
    Name:
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" placeholder="Type something" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    {{ name }}
</div>
<h1>
    Example 2</h1>
<div data-ng-init="names=['Sunil','Deepak','Rajat','Somu']">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h1>
    Example 3</h1>
<div>
    <h3>
        Adding a Simple Controller</h3>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a ng-href="#/View1.htm">View1</a>
</div>
```

DemoJS.js file code

```
var demoApp1 = angular.module('demoApp1', ['ngRoute'])

demoApp1.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/',
    {
        controller: 'SimpleController1',
        templateUrl: '/View2.htm'
    })
.when('View1',
{
    controller: 'SimpleController',
    templateUrl: '/View1.htm'
});
});


demoApp1.controller('SimpleController1', function ($scope) {
$scope.names = ['Dave', 'Napur', 'Heedy', 'Shriva'];
});


demoApp1.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {

$scope.customers = [
                    { name: 'Sunil', city: 'Delhi' },
                    { name: 'Ritu', city: 'Shbad' }
                    ];

$scope.addCustomer = function () {
    $scope.customers.push({ name: $scope.inputData.name, city: $scope.inputData.city });
}
});
```

Comment: Sir try using <script type="text/ng-template" id="view1.html"> for loading views.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake. The href link I used was not correct. As href is managed by angular itself, we should not add ".html" and the string we mention here should match to $routeProvide config string.. Below is the Modification I Made:

Incorrect on View1.html

```
<a ng-href="#/View2.htm">View2</a>
```

Corrected on View1.html:

```
<a href="#/view2">View2</a>
```

Samething I did on View2.html.